# Bonobo git server 6.3-unable to write hooks

Tags: windows, git, iis-8.5, bonobo

I want to restrict access to certain branches for certain users by using pre receive or pre push  hooks. But even an empty pre receive file( without an extension)  says pre receive hook declined.  Pre push just lets all push operations happen no matter the pre push script .

I have bonobo 6.3 on server 2012,  anonymous auth enabled in iis,  app data folder has been given access to,  anonymous checked in repo settings page of bonobo with anonymous push set to no. 
Could anyone help with the script? Am i missing something.?

Comment: Hi, have you found any solutions concerning the pre receive hooks with bonobo?